# Using class object from diffrent class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I’m having type script class which expose some service list

I’ve defined a property that should have reference to the `ServiceCatalog` class like following:

```
export default class myGenerator extends Generator {

  private svcat: ServiceCatalog | undefined;


  // and here I’ve initilzied the property 

 await this.getSvc();

// here I created some function the return service instances
private async getSvc() {
  this.svcat = new ServiceCatalog();
  await this.svcat.getServiceInstances();
}


// and here I’ve additional code which use it 

this.svcat.values  ….
```

My question is there Is a better/cleaner way of doing the in javascript/typescript ?
maybe not using the `this` keyword...

And also maybe a better code for testing (unit-test) ...

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear to me. You are trying to initialise the svCat and run the `getServiceInstances`? Can you paste the whole code of your class? Right now, this is not a valid Typescript class.

Comment: @Guilhermevrs - yes this is what im trying to do, the class is a lot longer... what is not valid ? `this.svcat.values  ….` i put it just an example for usage ...

Comment: @Guilhermevrs - what Im doing is calling to the class (serviceCatalog) and keep the object inside `myGenerator` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing today, it is very hard to test. Why is that? Well, because if you want to isolate your `Generator` class from your `ServiceCatalog`, you will have a hard time.

What I suggest, like the colleague above, is to have the `ServiceCatalog` coming by customer **BUT** have a default value.

```js
class MyGenerator extends Generator {
  constructor(private svCat: ServiceCatalog = new ServiceCatalog()) {
      super();
  }
}
```

This way you can use it normally like

```js
new MyGenerator()
```

or for testing

```js
new MyGenerator(myFakeServiceCatalog)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject the Service into your myGenerator class.
Add this to your constructor:

```
    constructor(private svcat:ServiceCatalog) {}
```

You can now access the injected Service using

```
    await this.svcat.getServiceInstances();
```

There is no need to add a property (your svcat:ServiceCatalog|undefined part) for the service.

**"this"** is needed a lot in java/type-script since it refers to the current class.